# HP P9500 block level data integrity checking

Tags: storage, hp

Does the HP P9500 do any sort of block level data integrity checking on reads?

If so, I'm looking for actual documentation that it does indeed do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

The P9000 Database Validator implements Oracle's HARD framework which can validate the Oracle block structure, block integrity, and block location with numerous checks [(more info)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10726/apphard.htm).

> Database Validator provides the P9500 Disk Array with an added level
>   of data protection when deployed in Oracle database environments.
>   Implementing Oracle's Hardware Assisted Resilient Data (HARD)
>   framework, it detects and corrects potential data corruption
>   introduced in the data I/O path and helps customers avoid unplanned
>   downtime. It can be deployed in HP UX/LVM and Sun Solaris/VxVM
>   environments. It is also supported in MC/ServiceGuard for HP UX
>   environments. When implemented in a complete Oracle HARD/P9500 Disk
>   Array solution, Database Validator works in conjunction with Oracle
>   HARD enabled databases to ensure that possible data corruptions
>   emanating from the connectivity path between the server and the P9500
>   are detected and rejected before they are committed to storage. If an
>   invalid/corrupt I/O is detected, Database Validator rejects the I/O
>   and reports the rejection to server and requests I/O retransmission.
>   At the same time, a SIM event message is passed to c track for remote
>   notification. Database Validator works in combination with other P9500
>   hardware and software to provide a complete Oracle HARD
>   implementation.

Read more at the P9500 QuickSpecs PDF (page 28) [here](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13725_div/13725_div.pdf)

Comment: Handy to know, but this doesn't actually answer the question. This handles the data path in between Oracle and the storage array.